# awk or sed to print text between the first occurance of a pattern and the last occurance of a pattern

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, nawk

i have seen a couple of solutions to print between patterns but am unable to put things together to cater to my problem.
I have a text file that contains a view definition  as shown below and need to extract the definition between the first and last braces.
Please note: there are open and closed braces in between which should be printed.
any solution in awk or sed?

```
create view view_name 
as(select column1 as someDATE,
    column2,
    column3,
    substring(convert(char(19),(DATEadd(hh,8,column4)),121),12) as someTIME,
    from table_name
    where NAME in('test')
    and column5='something')
```

**Output reqired:**

```
select column1 as someDATE,
column2,
column3,
substring(convert(char(19),(DATEadd(hh,8,column4)),121),12) as someTIME,
from table_name
where NAME in('test')
and column5='something'
```

Comment: It would help to know what is surrounding this pattern.  I guess it is no use to just strip the last character (the closing parenthesis) and the first 24 or so characters.  Especially: How do you recognize the end of the pattern?  Can it be done *only* by properly counting opening and closing parentheses?  Then I'd propose to use a decent parser and not just `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: The number of characters before the first open parenthesis could vary because the view_name could change. As for the last closing parenthesis, there would be no further characters. I was hoping there would be a way to identify the last occurance ... and of course the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude but effective:

```
sed -n -e '/(/,/)/p' filename | sed '1s/[^(]*(//;$s/)[^)]*$//'
```

**EDIT:**

(Corrected first solution.)

More sophisticated, but pulls the whole file into the hold space at once:

```
sed -n 'H;${x;s/^[^(]*(//;s/)[^)]*$//;p;}' filename
```

Comment: Doesn't strip the closing parenthesis in my test.

Comment: Thanks @Beta. That was really helpful. Been breaking my head all day trying to put 1+1=2

Comment: The first solution misses the `from table_name` line.

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`:

```
awk '/\(/&&!x{x=1;sub(/^[^(]*\(/,"")} match($0,/\)[^)]*$/)>0&&x{printf"%s",b substr($0,1,RSTART-1);b=substr($0,RSTART)"\n";next} x{b=b$0"\n"}' filename
```

It buffers text since first occurrence of `(` (or later appearances of `)`) into the `b` variable. When a `)` later appears, it prints the buffer (and the current line up to last `)`), and buffers the rest of the line into `b`.